# ScheduledExecutorService How to know either 1 of runnables finish

Tags: java, multithreading

I am using `ExecutorService` with thread pool of 3 or 4. I am scheduling them as `scheduleWithFixedDelay` method. What I wanna do is when one of tasks finishes  *I want to run a new thread* **everytime**. My runnables are a class and not implemented in the current class. Below you can find my execution of tasks mentioned above. I couldn't use `CountDownLatch` because you can not instantiate it again. How would I know when either finishes.

```
public class StatisticRunnable implements Runnable  {

    private boolean checkWaitingOnCustomer;
    private int start,end;
    private Main main;

    public StatisticRunnable(int start, int end, boolean checkWaitingOnCustomer, Main main) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
        this.checkWaitingOnCustomer = checkWaitingOnCustomer;
        this.main = main;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        main.runStatisticsInBackground(start,end, checkWaitingOnCustomer);
    }
}
```

**In my main class**

```
 statisticsExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(statisticsThreadCount);
            int average = (int) (Math.ceil((usersForStatistics.size()*1d)/(statisticsThreadCount *1d)));
            boolean checkKullanicidaBekliyor = false;
            for(int start = 0;  start < usersForStatistics.size(); start+= average){
                int end =start + average - 1;
                if(end > usersForStatistics.size()-1){
                    end = usersForStatistics.size()- 1;
                    checkKullanicidaBekliyor = true;
                }
                statisticsExecutor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new StatisticRunnable(start,end,checkKullanicidaBekliyor,this),2,DefaultValues.statisticsRefreshTime,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }
```

Comment: @Andreas obsolete reply which i can not label as. How do you think i know it can not be instantiated? I am trying to show my ways or way of thinking. You read how to understand and answer maybe?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow where people are egoistic and have tendency to gang up to downvote undeserved questions. The way the speak may disturb you thus please dont take it personally. SO community started to become toxic.

Comment: Sorry, I focused on the small part of the question that made even a little sense to me. If you only rejected `CountDownLatch` because it couldn't be restarted, then solution is to use `CyclicBarrier`. If that's not why you rejected it, then why even mention it? --- Anyway, question reads as an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/351454), and/or a very badly phrased question. Why would you want to start a new *thread* every time a scheduled *task* completes? What are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: @Andreas For utilization mostly. When a core becomes empty,i want not to waste it and do some stuff till next start of that task. But that task is not one of scheduled tasks.

Comment: So you want a job engine that can run priority tasks and normal tasks, ensuring that a priority task always runs when it wants to, and only running normal tasks when priority tasks are not using all threads of the thread pool?

Comment: Yes and when you put it this way i think it is a little bit complicated what i thought at first.